# Populate and array from another one

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and typescript and I have an issue.

I have an array that I create and I want to implement properties and values to this array from another one but when I try to do so, the array length stay to one, for example I want to add properties **longueur** and **quantity** depending on the values from the second array but here's what I get :

[Array that needs to be implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quK9o.png)

I do a forEach on an Array to get the elements I want to implements in the array but doesn't seems to work ( maybe I do it not in the proper way )

[Array that populate the other one with longueur and quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVR8t.png)

So basically, my array length should be the same as the one that populates it ( array in first picture should be lenght of 22, each index having **longueur** and **quanitity** from the other array ).

Here's my code sample :

component.ts :

```
quotDetails: any;
arrayWithValues: Array<any>;
copy: any;



initQuot() {
    this.service.checkExistQuot().subscribe(res => {
      this.quotArray = res;
      this.quotDetails = res.quotation.quotationdetail;
      this.arrayWithValues = new Array<any>(['longueur','quantity']);
      this.quotDetails.forEach((myArray, index) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.arrayWithValues.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.quotDetails)
          this.arrayWithValues[i].longueur = myArray.longueur;

        }console.log(this.arrayWithValues)
      })
    })
  }
```

If anyone can help me find the answer and explain what I'm doing wrong there I would really appreciate it, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` and `Object Destructuring` for your purpose

```
this.arrayWithValues=this.quotDetails.map( ({ longueur,quantity }) => ({ longueur,quantity }))
```

Example:

```js
let quotDetails=[
{
  longeur:1,
  quantity:1,
  id:1,
  quotationId:49,
  totalFurniture:"123"
},
{
  longeur:3,
  quantity:5,
  id:2,
  quotationId:47,
  totalFurniture:"323"
},
{
  longeur:5,
  quantity:0,
  id:3,
  quotationId:48,
  totalFurniture:"23"
}
]
console.log(quotDetails.map( ({longeur,quantity})=> ({longeur,quantity})))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you ! :)